# Apple Watch Glance data from HTML

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

I have an app that retrieves some data from a **HTML** page, and then process this. 
I would like some of this data to be visible on my Apple Watch on a Glance Page.
For some reason I can't get my head around how this works.

I've tried the basics with `NSUserdefaults` `- initWithSuitName`, enable App groups for my App, the Apple watch extensions and Apple Watch App, but every time I run the Glance in the Simulator, the NSUserdefaults appear to be empty?

Comment: Martin, Are you making watchOS 2 app?

Comment: Hi, well yes, noticed it's a bit easier from that point of view as the OS 2 app can handle a lot of things by it self now. I will give that a go, thanks.

Comment: Yes but please note that watch documents directory won't be on phone so you must make device synchronize nsuserdefaults and files via conectivity framework